# Stackexchange DNS seems to be down

Tags: support, status-completed, stackexchange-2.0, downtime

According to discussion in our [chat](http://chat.rpg.stackexchange.com/transcript/3), and [downforeveryoneorjustme](http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/rpg.stackexchange.com), http://rpg.stackexchange.com is down.  I can still access it, so I think it's a DNS thing.

**Update:** Gaming seems down too, and a number of others mentioned in the comments

**Update:** Everything seems solidly back up.  2010-10-12 10:55 EST.

Comment: English Language and Usage, too. I had just composed a comment there, and bam, it got eaten.

Comment: Cooking is down too.

Comment: And Unix, if any more examples are needed :). WA and AU both seem fine, and the trilogy

Comment: Android is also down

Comment: Since it hasn't been mentioned yet, Webmasters is up.

Comment: @rchern: it's down for me (and [downforeveryoneorjustme](http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/webmasters.stackexchange.com)).

Comment: Gaming is up for me

Comment: possible duplicate of [http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/ is "Unknown Host"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67370/http-meta-webapps-stackexchange-com-is-unknown-host)

Comment: @ChrisF I would probably close in the other direction, since this is older and has a bunch of comments

Comment: @Michael - I normally check, but didn't in this case. The other one's been closed now though.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/ is up while http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/ is down o_O

Comment: @KennyTM Both down for me. I imagine *.stackexchange.com is down depending on who does the query

Comment: NOT **PROGRAMMING**!! Waah!

Comment: I'll toss my coin in the lot. I can access meta.gaming, but not gaming.

Comment: Grace Note: Guess one of those is cached while the other is not. :-)

Comment: @TomWij Nope, not cached. It's working for me. I can even see the current UTC time, as well as pages I definitely had not navigated to prior.

Comment: Interesting that I can see some sites but not others.

Comment: Whoops, I meant "Programmers", but I think the others figured it out.

Comment: @Grace, it's the DNS entry that's cached, not the pages.  I'm sure that if you flush your DNS cache it would stop working.

Comment: All sites are up again for me!

Comment: @Aarobot Actually, flushing my DNS cache made Gaming *work*. My guess is this might be resolved now.

Comment: I'm not sure why people are closing this as "too localized", but it's a bug report, so you probably shouldn't...

Comment: @Michael Mrozek: The "bug" is fixed. I'm closing as "too localized" in lieu of the now-defunct [closed as no longer relevant]. It's the most applicable reason because "too localized" includes the phase, "a specific moment in time"... which has now passed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was a result of my ignorance of how wildcard mappings work.  I had converted our wildcard mapping but left some sub domains around.  If a subdomain still exists, at least with our DNS provider's implementation, it will not resolve.

In Summary:

*.foo.com does not work for arf.foo.com even if arf.foo.com doesn't exist if baz.arf.foo.com does.

As far as the `kyle.stackoverflow.com` entry, I am will have to contact our provider to find out why that is there.

Comment: +1. It is extremely refreshing to have an admin admit they made a mistake. I wish more admin's would learn that trait.

Answer (score 4):

`% dig cstheory.stackexchange.com.`

> stackexchange.com. 59  IN  SOA ns1.p19.dynect.net. kyle.stackoverflow.com. 53 3600 600 604800 60

Each of the four servers listed for `stackexchange.com` has the same information.  That "53" looks like someone made a typo and replaced the zone serial number with the port number for DNS, and perhaps the rest of the zone file is borked also.  I suggest the StackExchange folks get in touch with the person who last edited the stackexchange.com zone file.  I will email kyle@stackoverflow.com too.

Comment: Or the serial number is 53 by accident, but that wouldn't conform to guidelines to have something like: 2010101201 (year/month/day/edit)

Comment: It seems highly unlikely that stackexchange.com, which hosts dozens of sites that are in the Area 51 process, would only have been edited 52 times.

Comment: Looks fixed now, the 60 second time-to-live will cause this to hang around for a little while but it should be back to normal shortly.

Answer (score 3):

All sites that have alternate URLs are reachable through those URLS.  No site can be reached through its .stackexchange.com URL right now.  Something's up with the StackExchange DNS server.  What, I do not know.

Comment: Chinese hackers, that's what.

Comment: except for http://meta.stackexchange.com and http://area51.stackexchange.com and non-existent ones like http://somewhere.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I guess the DNS itself would be up as the chats are still available, but the other entries are acting weird.

The sites itself are up too, as adjusting the HOSTS file helps:

```
69.59.196.211 gaming.stackexchange.com
69.59.196.211 meta.gaming.stackexchange.com
```

Comment: that's twice http://stackoverflow.com for me - you mention the same IP twice!

Comment: That's how HOSTS files work... ;-)