# SEDE caching issue

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

SEDE has been updated, but apparently the query results are being cached and thus showing old results. Example:

http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/582/find-most-recent-post

http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/585/most-recent-post-2

Note that the queries are essentially the same, but the first one shows outdated results.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stackexchange DNS seems to be down.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67369/stackexchange-dns-seems-to-be-down)

Comment: @ChrisF - I think the question relates to the data here http://odata.stackexchange.com

Comment: Uh, how is it "Noise and Pointless"? And @ChrisF, Barry is right.

Comment: While your title does kinda cover the question, it would be helpful to use the question body to state *something*. Like, say, "The data-dump for September has been available for a while, but SEDE has not updated for it. When is it going to be updated?". That might counter the "Noise and Pointless".

Comment: Sorry - I misread the question title and as it followed on from a batch of DNS questions I assumed - always a bad thing.

Comment: The page now says it has been updated, but queries relating to SO still return data only up to the end of August. Queries for other stackexchange sites appear to work up to Septemeber. Weird.

Comment: Perhaps the data is being loaded now?

Comment: Possibly a caching issue; I can see that the data is up-to-date when I connect to the OData endpoint directly from LinqPad.

Comment: Too localized? That's an *example*. This problem affects **all** queries.

Comment: @NullUserException: It's still showing the August data for me too. Does everyone else see the same?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, forgot to dump the cache

Comment: SHAME! No waffles for you today!

Comment: @Ladybug, Its Sunday, on Sunday I ALWAYS get waffles, no matter what :p

Comment: I think you're confused. It's Saturday, not Sunday. Why do you damn Aussies always think forward and upside-down?! >:(

Comment: @Matt Ball: It is Sunday according to UTC time (as of this writing).

Comment: Still showing that the latest results are from Sep 10 for me :(

Answer (score 0):

There was [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/creative-commons-data-dump-oct-10/) last Thursday (7th) which said the data dump should be on SE in the next few days.  Although they did have a [few problems with power](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/stack-overflow-outage-2/) [and such](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67114/stack-overflow-outage) so they were probably a bit busy.

**UPDATE:**

The [SEDE](http://odata.stackexchange.com/) has been updated - the data is now at Sep 30 2010

Comment: See my updated post

Comment: @NullUserException - Ah I see your point.  One for a Mod I reckon?