# SEDE update is missing data from the past few months

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

I noticed a problem running queries on odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries.  The info in the right rail looks correct for the recent update.  Date and number of questions is right.  But the actual queries don't seem to include any data from the past few months.

I noticed first from the "[How many upvotes do I have](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/89/how-many-upvotes-do-i-have-for-each-tag)" query, it shows tags with a count well less than what's required to get a badge.  Got the badge a while ago.  Other queries didn't change either from their results before the update.  Perhaps the easiest one to see the problem at is "[Total questions and answer per month](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/282/total-questions-and-answers-per-month-for-the-last-12)", July is the last reported month.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SEDE caching issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67391/sede-caching-issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry, forgot to dump the cache