# data stackexchange still caching results

Tags: support, data-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are my SEDE results inaccurate/obsolete/incorrect/outdated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130856/why-are-my-sede-results-inaccurate-obsolete-incorrect-outdated)

Although [this post says status-completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67391/sede-caching-issue) for the **caching problem** on [data.stackexchange](http://data.stackexchange.com), I'm still getting pretty old results. My suspicion led me to thinking results were being cache and was confirmed when I noticed different values for my rep and comment scores when I visited the actual posts/comments.

Can somebody verify if this has/will be fixed or any work-arounds? Or when will the cache be cleared/dumped next?

Comment: SEDE doesn't have live data, it was last updated Jun 26. Are you sure your results weren't valid on Jun 26?

Comment: @YannisRizos: Oh! I never knew that. I was under the impression query results were cached. Hmm. Then, I guess they should have been correct as of that date. Please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data Explorer doesn't have live data, and according to its [FAQ](https://data.stackexchange.com/faq) it's on a monthly update cycle. It was last updated on June 26th, so the data are valid up until then. You can see when the data was last updated on the [front page](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Ah! No wonder I missed it. Since the first time I visited I've had the [queries page](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) in my bookmarks. They should consider putting that info at the bottom of every query result.